# python for loop not executing enough times

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I am trying to make a game in pygame. The program involves looping through an array of objects, and determining whether they collide with another object.
However, when I run the for loop it doesn't execute as many times as there is objects in the list.

```
print(f"Length of array: {str(len(Crate.Crates))}")
counter = 0
   for crate in Crate.Crates:
       counter += 1
       if crate.colide and crate.rect.colliderect(self.explosionRect):
           crate.hitByBall()
print(f"loop has executed {str(counter)} times")
```

The output I get after running this code is the following:

```
Length of array: 25
loop has executed 23 times
```

Here is the GitHub repository where you can find the entire code: https://github.com/Mateusz9/game
(the code fragment mentioned above is located *game/crates/Bomb/crate.py*)

Comment: What does `hitByBall` do? Does it remove objects for the list? If so, iterate a copy tf the list  `for crate in Crate.Crates[:]:`

Comment: Try printing length of array after for loop

Comment: thanks @Rabbid76. Iterating over the copy of the list works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method `crate.hitByBall()` method removes objects from the list, you must iterate over a copy of the list (see also [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)):

<s>`for crate in Crate.Crates:`</s>

```py
for crate in Crate.Crates[:]:
```